# Laravel execl Import with additional Fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

```
Excel::import(new Import(), request()->file('filename'));
```

I want to import extra Fields
  `$request->field1 , $request->fild2`
From input field..
I'm using Maatwebsite\Excel

Comment: $file_info = Excel::load($request_file,
                    function ($reader) use ($request) {
});

Have you tried something like this?
In $request you will get value of extra param you want to pass.

Comment: im using 3.1 version

Comment: Then Try passing it in "new Import($request)" and catch it in constructor of Import class you will have those data there to import.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get request data in import like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Model;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class BulkImportLead implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $request = request()->all();
        $field1 = $request['field1'];
        $field2 = $request['field2'];

        //here your import code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Students;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class StudentsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow

{

    public function model(array $row)
    {

        $request = request()->all();

        return new Students([

            'matno'=> $row['matno'],
            'name'=> $row['name'],
            'dept'=> $row['dept'],
            'level'=> $row['level'],
            'deptid'=> $request['deptid']   

        ]);
    }
}
```